# Using a .bat file to compress jpg inside a folder imagemagick magick

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg

EDIT (FINAL)

I figured it out!

Step 1: install image magick on windows

Step 2: locate the file magick.exe in program files. keep a copy of this somewhere convenient. you'll be making copies of this everytime you have a folder of photos.

Step 3: Create a batch file, (notepad save as .bat) (e.g. magick.bat) and keep this file in that same convenient location as Step 2. you'll also be making copies of this everytime you have a folder of photos. the batch code as follows:

```
@ECHO ON

  FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO magick convert %%a -quality 95%% %%~na_small.jpg

PAUSE
```

Step 4: Copy both .bat and magick.exe into a folder of your photos each time you want to compress the photos inside, then double click the .bat batch file and let it run! Your compressed photos will start appearing!

[sample of how folder looks][1]

I'm really not good at this. I just want to create a .bat file, copy and paste this file into a folder where my photos are, and then double click this file so that I can compress my jpgs

but with my echo on, i can see that it keeps looping the first jpg and then it stops. nothing happens after that. no new files are created either, or overwritten.

can someone point me the proper code to write?

```
@ECHO ON

pause

for %%A In (*.jpg) do (magick -i "%%A" -quality 85 "%%~nAx.jpg")

PAUSE
```

thank you

Edit: this is how it looks like with Echo ON

````
I:\Photos\unsorted\testing>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

I:\Photos\unsorted\testing>for %A In (*.jpg) do (magick -i "%A" -quality 85 "%~nAx.jpg" )

I:\Photos\unsorted\testing>(magick -i "XH1F0270.JPG" -quality 85 "XH1F0270x.jpg" )

I:\Photos\unsorted\testing>pause
Press any key to continue . . .```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhhEx.png
````

Comment: What do you mean "then it stops"?  Does it reach the second `pause`?  Copy the full output from the console and add it to your question.

Comment: Why not just use ImageMagick mogrify to do that. It processes a whole folder of files without having to write a script loop. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify.

Comment: @paddy edited my post to include the console's message.

Comment: @fmw42  can i clarify that to use mogrify, i have to open cmd, and cd all the way to my photos folder and use the mogrify function there? if so, i really am hoping for some help to fix the .bat file because otherwise i have to keep using cmd to get to my photos

Comment: You can put paths in mogrify so that you do not have to cd to the image directory. You can also use the -path option to specify the output directory. For example in unix syntax: `mogrify -path desktop/test2 -format png desktop/test1/*.jpg` will process all jpg files in my test1 directory on my desktop and put the results as pngs into my test2 folder on my desktop. I was running that mogrify command from my home directory. Sorry, I am on a Mac and do bash shell scripts. I do not know Windows .bat scripts syntax. But my mogrify command would be the same for .bat except the file paths use \ not /

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Step 1: install image magick on windows

Step 2: locate the file magick.exe in program files. keep a copy of this somewhere convenient. you'll be making copies of this everytime you have a folder of photos.

Step 3: Create a batch file, (notepad save as .bat) (e.g. magick.bat) and keep this file in that same convenient location as Step 2. you'll also be making copies of this everytime you have a folder of photos. the batch code as follows:

@ECHO ON

FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO magick convert %%a -quality 95%% %%~na_small.jpg

PAUSE

Step 4: Copy both .bat and magick.exe into a folder of your photos each time you want to compress the photos inside, then double click the .bat batch file and let it run! Your compressed photos will start appearing!